# How to construct delete route in link_to in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Having 2 models customer and comm_log. Their association is as below:

```
resources :customers do
  comm_logs
end
```

The rspec code for destroy in comm_logs controller passed without any error. The lambda block verified that the comm log count was reduced by 1 after a successful delete. Everything in controller seems right.

The output of rake routes is:

```
       new_customer_comm_log GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/new(.:format)                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
      edit_customer_comm_log GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id/edit(.:format)            {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
           customer_comm_log GET    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
                             PUT    /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
                             DELETE /customers/:customer_id/comm_logs/:id(.:format)                 {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comm_logs"}
```

In reality, the record was not deleted after clicking the delete button and the page was not redirected to previous page as it is in the controller (the show page just remains and did not redirect to anywhere after deleting). It seems that the delete action was routed to the right path. The problem is most likely with the link_to below in views:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', customer_comm_log_path(@customer, @comm_log), :method => :delete, :confirm => "are you sure?", :remote => true %>
```

Is there anything wrong in link_to above? thanks.

Comment: Can you post your controllers destroy method?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you may be missing.  I'm assuming you're using jQuery since you didn't specify in your question.

a) Make sure you have jQuery installed

b) Make sure you have installed the Rails UJS (Unobtrusive Javascript) adapter either manually or using the gem (instructions for Rails 3.1 are on this link as well): https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

c) Your `link_to` needs to tell the Rails UJS adapter that it should capture the link's click and submit the `DELETE` request via AJAX

```
<%= link_to 'delete', customer_comm_log_path(@customer, @comm_log), :remote => true, :method => :delete) %>
```

So in the `link_to` above, you were missing `:remote => true`

Rails will capture the user's click on that link and then kick off a jQuery `$.ajax` call to your server that includes a couple params to tell the Rails server that it is a remote DELETE request.

d) If you're redirecting in the controller via the user clicking a remote link like that, you need to tell Rails to handle the AJAX redirects properly by placing this code in your `ApplicationController`.  If you don't do this, the link will delete the record but then it will just sit there and not redirect.

```
  # Allows redirecting for AJAX calls as well as normal calls
  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
    if request.xhr?
      render(:update) {|page| page.redirect_to(options)}
    else
      super(options, response_status)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am running rails 3.1.0, jquery seems have been installed. There was gem 'jquery-rail' in Gemfile. In application.js, there were require jquery and require jquery.ui. Just added jquery.ujs. Added the def code in the post for ajax redirect to application_controller.rb. Besides to :remote => true, also added :confirm => true to the link_to. There is no confirmation fired up when clicking the delete. No redirect as well. The record is still there.

Comment: What do the server logs say (i.e. is the request ever hitting the server)?  Also, check your browser's console for javascript errors.  If you have a JS error, then it won't execute the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: After creating a new.js.erb file and added respond_to with both html and js format in lease_logs controller, the ajax destroy posted above started to work. There are 2 lines in new.js.erb: $("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'lease_logs/new.html.erb') %>").insertAfter('#new_log_link');
$('#new_log_link').hide();

Comment: Also added destroy.js.erb to views. It is one line file which is $("#<%= dom_id(@lease_log) %>").remove()